# Jquery ByPass beforeunload for one link?

Tags: php, jquery, onbeforeunload

I'm using `$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){` on my page and it seems to be working fine.

BUT.. I'd like to disable it if one link is clicked :

```
<a id="delete" href="<?php echo $script?>?delete=all" onClick="return confirm('Delete All ?')">DELETE</a>
```

Otherwise I get the prompt from the link then I'm asked if I want to navigate away from the page. Ideally I only want the prompt then the page is reloaded.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to unbind the event like this:

```
 $('#delete').on('click', function(e){
        $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    });
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I still get the prompt and the beforeunload.

Comment: yeah, sorry I didn't understand well the question, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Got this working, thought I should share how !

```
$('#delete').click(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault(); 
var r=confirm("Delete All ?"); 
if (r==true)   {  
$.ajax({ url : 'script.php?delete=all' 
     }); 
   } 
});
```

and added `id="delete"` to the a href.

Thanks :)